# Parallel processes, ignore_user_abort and set_time_limit(0)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, parallel-processing

We're working on a system that uses **ignore_user_abort()** and **set_time_limit(0)** in one of the scripts.

We have to send one HTTP 1.1 packet to this script, with **Jquery** and then we have to resume and keep using other scripts inside the application.

But once the packet is sent, the session **is somehow locked,** and if you try to refresh or load any other script inside the domain, with the same browser, it **won't load until the previous one finishes** (and that might take more than 2 hours).

However it's possible to keep using the application from another browser, with the same username and password, which makes me think it's related to the session.

We need to prevent this or solve this somehow, to make this script run as a background processes without interfering with the functioning of the rest of the application.

Any idea how, or why this happens and how we could solve it?

***The AJAX request looks like this:***

```
<script>
$('#launch').click(function () {

//acomodamos la UI
$('#launch').hide();
$('#c_wait').slideUp();
$('#c_started').fadeIn("slow");

//send the request
$.get("modules/_map.php", { funcion: "launch", scan_id: "<?php echo $scan->id; ?>" } );                     
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post the `ajax()` calls you're making and also any `ajaxSetup()` calls that you might be making. It sounds like you're using synchronous requests, which will lock up the browser (even on other tabs).

Comment: Yes, of course, let me update the question. I thought the same before, but it seems like it does the same if we send the request directly from the browser...

Comment: sounds to me like a database lock on data which is just fetched/written within the same unique session. what is the output of `show processlist` when the process is running + you have a pending "hanging" response running in the same browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be right - the problem could very well be session-related (your JavaScript doesn't indicate synchronous requests are being performed).

If you are running a long request that uses session information, you may find it beneficial to use the following code as a template for how you manage the session data:

```
// start the session
session_start();

// manipulate session data
// e.g.,
// $some_var = $_SESSION['some_var'];
// $_SESSION['some_var'] = 'something';

// flush any changes to the session and close
session_write_close();

// Start the long process here...
```

By using this approach you can manipulate the session before the long request starts, and then unlock it for subsequent requests using the same session.

Comment: don't get this. how this would block new requests in the same session? you think this could be the reason for a server holding back the response?

Comment: When you call `session_start()` it locks the session object through its driver (most people use files, so it locks the session file). This is to protect the file from being corrupted by concurrent writes from different requests. Can you imagine the chaos if a client could make multiple requests with the same session, blanket writing to the file while other requests are still in progress? There was actually [a bug filed many years ago](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=31464), which explains the issue (they also recommend the same solution).

Comment: Brilliant, we're gonna try this now, I'll let you know in a moment how it works :) Thanks plasmid87!